# How to convert a DateTime object to Local/UTC Timezone in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, timezone

I would like to know if it is possible to convert a DateTime object's timezone in a **Linq Query**. For example

```
var seats = await _seat.GetAll()
                    .Where( 
                       DbFunctions.AddHours( x.StartTime, -1 ) >= x.CreationTime.ToUniversalTime());
```

In the above code, x.StartTime is in *UTC* timezone whereas x.Creation time is in *local* timezone. if I call **ToUniversalTime()** on x.CreationTime I get an exception.
Is it possible to do the conversion inside the Linq query?
I know it is possible to extract CreationTime before the query and convert it, but it would be great to know the possibility to convert it inside the Linq quert exists.

Comment: What exception do you get?  Does `_seat.GetAll()` pull from a database?

Comment: The appearance of `DbFunctions` in your code indicates that you are using Entity Framework. Is that true? The answer to your question will be specific to the LINQ provider that translates the LINQ query into SQL.

Comment: A few questions:  1) Is this Entity Framework?  2) Is this SQL Server or something else? (and what version?) 3) What field types are `StartTime` and `CreationTime` in the database?  4) *Why* are you storing local time in the `CreationTime` field?  5) *Who's* local time is it - the user's?  A web server's? The database server's?  6) You do realize your query is [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), right?

Comment: @BJMyers I get this exception: ** LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToUniversalTime()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. **

Comment: @MartinLiversage Correct, I'm using Entity Framework. I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by: "The answer to your question will be specific to the LINQ provider that translates the LINQ query into SQ"

Comment: @MattJohnson  1) Is this Entity Framework? yes 2) It is Microsoft Sql server 2016 3) StartTime is datetime2 in the ´database and CreationTime is of type DateTime which is set to DateTime.Now 5) Who's local time is it? The user's local time 6) You do realize your query is non-sargable, right? I just realized that :)

Comment: @arvind: You can easily solve your problem by pulling all the rows to the client side and then perform the filtering using your predicate (putting aside the problems created by using "local time".) However, I assume that you want to filter the records on the database server. EF will have to translate your predicate to corresponding SQL and that limits what you can do in the `Where` clause. The `DbFunctions` is a way to declare certain simple computations that EF can translate to SQL but there is no way to perform time zone conversions. SQL Server has no concept of time zones.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks a lot for your help, now I know I shouldn't try to convert timezone :)

Comment: @Martin - Actually, SQL Server 2016 just added time zone support.  However, there aren't EF DbFunctions for them yet, AFAIK.  Still, probably not a good usage here.

Answer (score 1):

As @MartinLiversage explained in the columns the best solution would be as follows:

**You can easily solve your problem by pulling all the rows to the client side and then perform the filtering using your predicate (putting aside the problems created by using "local time".) However, I assume that you want to filter the records on the database server. EF will have to translate your predicate to corresponding SQL and that limits what you can do in the Where clause. The DbFunctions is a way to declare certain simple computations that EF can translate to SQL but there is no way to perform time zone conversions. SQL Server has no concept of time zones.**

And as @Martine mentioned the following could be taken into considertion:

**SQL Server 2016 just added time zone support. However, there aren't EF DbFunctions for them yet, AFAIK. Still, probably not a good usage here.**